# Invalid bundle OS type code while uploading build on itunes

Tags: ios, itunes-store

Getting following error while uploading the app on AppStore.

I know the reason of second warning but don't know the reason of first error.

[image]

I have set the following parameters in my Plist -

1) Bundle OS Type code - APPL

2) Bundle Identifier - com.company.appname

3) Bundle display name - Appname

Anyone can help me.

Comment: Post you info.plist file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change Bundle OS type code to BNDL and Bundle Creator OS Type Code to ????.

Answer (score 14):

Make sure you have that in your .plist file:

```
<key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
<string>APPL</string>
```

If you have several targets (release / debug maybe) make sure you changed that in the configuration you are posting - potentially you have several .plist files in your project.